# I'm wondering if there is "whereType" and "whereGender" on Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm looking at the Eloquent Documentation and found this line:

```
public function scopeWomen($query)
{
    return $query->whereGender('W');
}
```

and..

```
public function scopeOfType($query, $type)
{
    return $query->whereType($type);
}
```

Is there `whereGender` and `whereType` function? As I look at the API documentation I found nothing under `Eloquent/Builder` and `Query/Builder`. If it is a user-defined function I'll be happy if there is somebody can teach me on how to do that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look up "query scopes". It's a "magic" feature in Laravel 4:
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes

Example:

```
Model::whereColumn_name('someValue')->get();
```

Example 2:

```
Model::where("column_name", "=", "someValue")->get();
```

Query with both versions will look like:

```
WHERE column_name = 'someValue'
```